register_rest_route to send via ajax as guest results to 403
I am trying to submit a contact form post request via ajax as guest. The code is written as follows:
    add_action('rest_api_init', [$this, 'contact_form_api']);
    
    public function contact_form_api()
    {
        register_rest_route(
            'contact-form/v1',
            'send-contact-form',
            array(
                'methods' => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
                'callback' => array($this, 'save_form'),
                'permission_callback' => '__return_true' // allow everyone to submit
            )
        );
    }

    function save_form($post_id)
    {
        ...
        // sanitize, submit, save to CPT
    }

    wp_nonce_field($this->nonce_key, $this->nonce_value);
    $contact_form_url = get_rest_url(null, "contact-form/v1/send-contact-form");

    event.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      var nonce = $("#nonce_contact_form").val();
      var url = <?php echo $contact_form_url;?>;
      console.log(nonce, url);
      $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        headers: {
          "X-WP-Nonce": nonce,
        },
        data: formData,
        // cache: false,
        processData: false,
      });

'permission_callback' => '__return_true' is needed to allow all users to submit post. But I am still getting 403.
The URL generated: http://localhost:8081/wp-json/contact-form/v1/send-contact-form
Note: I cant even get to my callback. It is stopping in the network
Error :"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce"

wp_nonce_field() is intended to echo out the nonce as a hidden field in your form, but above you seem to have it somewhere else. If you want to create a nonce outside of the form HTML you need to be using wp_create_nonce(). By default the API is expecting a nonce key of wp_rest. No idea what yours is, because you haven't included the constructor where you're setting $this->nonce_key.

I do have the nonce in the form as a hidden input. I just put nonce in a variable to be used with X-WP-Nonce header
